# Compiling wpf application to x64 fails after instalation

Tags: c#, wpf

I have written a WPF app for copying files and such. For reasons of merging pdfs I need to make my app x64. The application works fine as long as it is compiled x86. When I compile x64 it works in visual studio but fails after I install it to my or any other computer which uses 64bit windows.

When compiling my app I use "Any CPU" and disable "prefer 32bit".

The installation file is made with Visual Studio Installer.

When I start the installed application nothing happens.

So far I have checked that all referenced dll-s are compiled as "Any CPU".

How do I debug my situation.

Event log says:

Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.

Exception Info: System.UnauthorizedAccessException

Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.24231,
time stamp: 0x5b6db5dd

Exception code: 0xe0434352

Fault offset: 0x000000000001a06d

Faulting process id: 0xd54

Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll

Comment: `fails` is not a technical description of a problem. what are the event log error messages saying.

Comment: Thank you. I have added some of the event log messages.

Comment: A component that generates PDF very often uses unmanaged code.  So arbitrary changing the process bitness tends to be a problem.  But you must get ahead by being able to diagnose crashes like this, it is going to happen again in the future and you must know why without relying on help from a web site visitors that can't see your code.  Writing an event handler for the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException event is never really optional.

Comment: @Hans So you are proposing that I try catch the event and hadle it within my code?

Comment: "Handle it" is the wrong mental model, you can't handle an unhandled exception.  Simply report the exception (use its ToString() method so you get the call stack) and terminate the app with Environment.Exit().  Google "wpf how to report unhandled exceptions" to learn more.

Comment: @Hans, with your advice was able to catch the exception and see what I did wrong. My mistake vas trying to create a folder as soon as the application started in Program Files where IO operations would take place. After researching I now know that this is bad practice. Consequently I got denied access to the folder. If you wish you can write your comment as an answer and I will mark it as the accepted answer. Thank you for your insight.

Comment: Just share what you learned today in your own post and mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Hans Passant pointed me in the right direction I managed to solve my problem.

In my application I forgot to include a try catch statement in App.xaml.cs . After doing so I caught the exception which stated that the access to a certain folder in my application was denied.
The mistake I made was trying to create a folder in my installation location (c:\ProgramFiles...), which I later found out is not good practice. For some reason the x86 compiled application manages to see this fault and simply redirects these folders to the virtual store location, and doesn't bother you. But the application compiled as x64 throws an exception.

After finding the flaw I now simply need to make the folders somewhere else presumably in AppData.

Answer (score 0):

Launch Visual Studio as Administrator

Comment: My user is the administrator. I fail to see the point. Why would that make a diference?

Comment: Since the current Windows session context is nothing similar with the current process context. And considering you're trying to process changes/work on a protected file, that seemed a highly possible issue to me. Seems that it made no differences though ?